# How to enable/disable Jumbo Frames in NIC Card using VC++ programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, ethernet

I wanted to know how to enable or disable jumbo frames for installed NIC card programmatically.

For installed NIC card, we can set in using GUI. But I wanted to do it programmatically in VC++.

Comment: You can set it using which GUI?  One provided with the NIC driver?

Answer (score 0):

Never did it myself, so this is just a guess: ioctl with SIOCSIFMTU